# How to compile oneko progam under modern linux?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation

The program Oneko draws a little cat chasing the mouse coursor under Linux. As this program is quite old the cat's image is small on modern FullHD displays. As the source is available (http://www.daidouji.com/oneko/) I scaled up the images and now need to recompile the code.

First I tried `make` as a `makefile` is in the main directory (I had to rename the `Imakefile` to `makefile` beforehand), but got the error `Missing separator`. Therefore I tried to compile the code with `gcc` but failed with a lot of warnings which I don't understand.

```
manu@fuji:~/Downloads/oneko-1.2.sakura.5$ gcc oneko.c -o oneko-new
oneko.c:338:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 GetResources()
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
oneko.c:437:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 MakeMouseCursor()
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
oneko.c:466:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 SetupColors()
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
oneko.c: In function ‘InitScreen’:
oneko.c:627:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [-Wendif-labels]
 #endif SHAPE
        ^~~~~
[more errors below here]
```

Comment: The diagnostics shown are warnings. Although important (and should be taken care of) warnings [usually??] don't stop gcc from creating an executable.

Comment: Amazingly, this utility still exists in repositories for the latest Fedora Linux versions. Not sure about other distros. Are you sure you need to build it at all?

Comment: @pmg I only posted a snippet of the errors, sorry for missing the real error message. Nevertheless I found a github repository which displays the gcc command to compile the software from sources. With this I can compile the code. Nevertheless when I increase the sizes of the images from 32x32 to 64x64 I get display glitches in the newly compiled software. Therefore I tried to check the C code but was unable to find the code which allows large image sizes. Yes I have to, because there is no parameter to increase the image size, so I have to change the code and recompile it myself.